# React native error when i am running project on simulator

Tags: android, runtime-error, react-native

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

I tried to again install android studio same error happening.
Why is this issue happening??